# Increment input value using mouse wheel

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, input, dom-events, mousewheel

I'm trying to increase/decrease the value of input field using mouse wheel. I've put together the following code. It's working fine, but there's a small problem.

The behaviour I want is to be able to increment/decrement the input value using mouse wheel once I focus on the element. Mouse doesn't have to be hovering the element. The following code performs this. But if I use wheel while hovering the input element, the value is incremented/decremented by 2 instead of 1.

```js
var hoveredInput = null;

$('input[type="number"]').on("focus", function(e) {
  hoveredInput = this;
});
$('input[type="number"]').on("blur", function(e) {
  hoveredInput = null;
});

$(window).on("wheel", function(e) {
  if (hoveredInput) {
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      var currentValue = parseInt(hoveredInput.value, 10);
      var newValue = currentValue + 1;
      if (newValue > parseInt(hoveredInput.max, 10)) {
        newValue = hoveredInput.max;
      }
      hoveredInput.value = newValue;
    } else {
      var currentValue = parseInt(hoveredInput.value, 10);
      var newValue = currentValue - 1;
      if (newValue < parseInt(hoveredInput.min, 10)) {
        newValue = hoveredInput.min;
      }
      hoveredInput.value = newValue;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="255" />
```

After some experimenting, I figured that there's a similar behaviour for up and down arrow keys. Up and down arrow keys, on a number input, increments/decrements the value. And I suppose, this behaviour conflicts with my code. Causes it to increment by 2, even though the code doesn't execute twice.

---

I've just realized that this might be a Chrome specific problem. Chrome let's you increment/decrement number input value using mouse wheel if you focus and hover the element. However, it works in a really weird way.

If I just add `<input type="number" />` in a blank HTML page, this mouse wheel increment doesn't work. To make it work, I simply add `window.onwheel = function() {};`. This doesn't make any sense. Also this seems to work on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2v9thr3/) and JSBin without `onwheel` assignment on the `window`.

---

Going back to the actual problem, can I disable the default mouse wheel increment on the element, so that I can use my custom one? Or is there another approach that I can use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would be considering *not* using [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to prevent the default action. You are changing what the UI action will be under these circumstances. You should, of course, use `preventDefault()` to prevent the default action.  If you don't use `preventDefault()` then there would be some unexpected consequences to using the scroll wheel when the `<input type="number">` is focused. Without `preventDefault()`, what combination of unexpected consequences would occur under those conditions will depend on the browser that is being used to view the page.

I am unable to duplicate a conflict with using the cursor keys to change the input value. Obviously, if all you are using to limit the minimum and maximum values of the `<input>` is the code for the mouse wheel, then those limits will not function for any other method of entry.  You could use the `min` and `max` attributes for limiting values.  Doing so would be better for multiple reasons, including that it affects all methods of entering a value and as it allows defining those ranges per `<input>` instead of one set of limits for all `<input type="number">`.  I have changed the code so that your code also uses these attributes.

If you do this, you may want to consider adding a CSS style to indicate that the `<input type="number">` element has focus.  Doing so will make it more clear to the user why the mouse wheel is not doing what they normally expect from their browser's UI.

I suggest you try this with multiple browsers to see if it is something you desire. Personally, at least in the testing I have done on this page, I like the behavior.

**NOTE:**
Your use of the `focus` and `blur` events is overly complex. I have changed the code to directly find the focused element using [`document.activeElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/activeElement).

```js
//Exclude one specific element for comparing this UI vs. the browser's default.
var excludedEl = document.getElementById('exclude');

$(window).on("wheel", function(e) {
  focusedEl = document.activeElement;
  if(focusedEl === excludedEl){
    //Exclude one specific element for UI comparison 
    return;
  }
  if (focusedEl.nodeName='input' && focusedEl.type && focusedEl.type.match(/number/i)){
    e.preventDefault();
    var max=null;
    var min=null;
    if(focusedEl.hasAttribute('max')){
      max = focusedEl.getAttribute('max');
    }
    if(focusedEl.hasAttribute('min')){
      min = focusedEl.getAttribute('min');
    }
    var value = parseInt(focusedEl.value, 10);
    if (e.originalEvent.deltaY < 0) {
      value++;
      if (max !== null && value > max) {
        value = max;
      }
    } else {
      value--;
      if (min !== null && value < min) {
        value = min;
      }
    }
    focusedEl.value = value;
  }
});
```

```css
input[type="number"]:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 1.5px 1px cyan;
}

/*For comparing UIs: May conflict with browser default, or user's theme.*/
#exclude:focus {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
NOTE: Events are only caught while the mouse stays within the test portion of the stackoverflow page:<br/><br/><br/>

Uses changed UI (if focused, mouse wheel will increment/decrement):<br/>
<input type="number" value="0" id="firstNumberInput" min="0" max="255"/>
<br/>Uses browser default UI:
<input id="exclude" type="number" value="0" min="0" max="255" style="display:block"/>
```

Comment: This is so silly of me not thinking `preventDefault()`. And I did not know about `document.activeElement`. I also have another listener for input to handle min - max limits. I just didn't want to include it since it wasn't really related to problem at hand.